# I am posting data to server but server giving me this error "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" in mock api testing

Tags: javascript, json, axios, jestjs, json-server

I am posting data to server but server giving me this error  "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" in mock api testing

```
   const jsonServer = require('json-server')
const server = jsonServer.create()
const router = jsonServer.router('./db.json')
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults()
const db = require('./db.json');


server.use(middlewares)
server.get('/user', (request, response) => {
  // console.log('test');
  response.jsonp(req.query)
})


server.use(middlewares)

server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser)

const isAuthenticated = ({username,password})=>{
    return db.login.find(user => user.username === username && user.password === password)
}
server.post('/login', (req, res) => {

  if (!isAuthenticated(req.body) === false) {
    const response = {
      status : 401,
      message : 'Incorrect username or password'
    }
  
    return res.status(status).json(response)
  }
  
  res.status(200).json(res)
 
})

server.use(router)
server.listen(8000, () => {
console.log('JSON Server is running...')

})
```

I am posting data to server but server giving me this error  "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" in mock api testing

Comment: please edit your post and write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body.